# DB pull from heroku fails with Encoding::CompatibilityError

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having some problems performing a db:pull from heroku back to my local development enviroment.

My setup is MySQL (5.1.50) from a MacPorts install on a local Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.2 environment under Mac OS X Snow Leopard via RVM, and I've successfully performed a `heroku db:push` to the production site on Heroku many times. However, on a secondary development machine with the same setup, when I try and pull the Heroku DB back via `heroku db:pull`, I get the following error, after it downloads the table and index info for a short while:

```
/Users/jschuur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/mysql.rb:399:in `join': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Users/jschuur/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/sequel-3.15.0/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/mysql.rb:399:in `multi_insert_sql'
```

Here's the relevant gems:

```
ruby-mysql (2.9.3)
sequel (3.15.0)
mysql2 (0.2.4)
taps (0.3.13)
heroku (1.10.6, 1.10.5, 1.10.0)
```

Full error and gem list [here](https://gist.github.com/000498307d311e70aa2d).

The same error happens on my primary production machine BTW (the one where I've been doing the successful db:push to heroku form).

Now I understand that this is basically a UTF8 encoding error. FWIW, my database.yml explicitly references UTF8:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: rails_dev_dbname
  pool: 5
  username: rails
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Now interestingly, if I create an almost blank DB with just a single test entry in it, I can push/pull it fine. So obviously something in my dataset of non UTF8. While there's not a lot of data there yet, it's entirely possible that I copied some text among it that contains a funky quote or a copyright symbol that it's choking on.

So the question is, how do I get around this problem? The Heroku docs do mention [appending '?encoding=utf'](http://docs.heroku.com/taps) to your DB URL when you do a push, but I assume that my default `heroku db:push` that sent the data to Heroku in the first place used `database.yml`, which already has that set. Either way, I did an explicit push this way, and a subsequent pull still has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switch my ruby version to 1.8.7 when using taps to push and pull when I get errors so you might want to give that a try.

If you don't use this already use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your ruby versions

Comment: Huh. That did the trick, but why? Could have been some new defaults in 1.9 that conflicted with the taps gem assumptions. Thanks for the quick response.