# heroku db:pull returns "ArgumentError -> interning empty string"

Tags: ruby, heroku, taps

I'm trying to dump an heroku app's DB to my local database with taps

Gems :

- heroku (1.17.10)
- taps (0.3.15)

Running :

```
$ heroku db:pull --app myapp --confirm myapp
```

gives me :

```
Failed to connect to database:
  ArgumentError -> interning empty string
```

What could be the reason ?

Comment: are you using ruby 1.9 on your local machine and/or your heroku stack?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the exact error you're getting, but [taps and Ruby 1.9 don't seem to play well together](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues#issue/65).

In case you're using Ruby 1.9 on the client side, you can try switching to Ruby 1.8 for taps push/pull (as [suggested by sam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847760/db-pull-from-heroku-fails-with-encodingcompatibilityerror))

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't in taps : my database.yml was broken !

If you get this error, check out your database config, it happens when taps wants connect to the local database.